# Undefined index Notice

Tags: php, html, undefined, isset, notice

I've tried to fix this for ages, but when I try to upload a file I get an "`undefined index`" notice. Any help would be great! I get the error on line 38 if that helps, also I think it might be something to do with my form too.

HTML form:

```
    <form action="UploadFileCodeImage.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload image (JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF):<br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="file">
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$destination = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Uploaded files\CS\Image";
$target_file = $destination . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$filetype = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = filesize($_FILES["file"]["Temp"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "Voila! - " . $check["file"];
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($filetype != "jpg" && $filetype != "png" && $filetype != "jpeg"
&& $filetype != "gif") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, and GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["Temp"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Must be the 5th undefined index Q in 30 mins.

Comment: This is wrong `["Temp"]` - [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Oh and this will never fire up anything `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` - have you not done any basic debugging? Not to mention two elements holding the same name attribute.

Comment: Ah thanks, I have next to none experience with this. Do you know exactly what's making it return undefined index?

Comment: You're welcome. The answers are in my comments and 1/2 of which can be found in 2 of the answers below, where each are only 50% right. ;-)

Comment: I decided to post an answer and you can view it below. @DorsVenabili

Comment: @DorsVenabili I've spotted a few more errors and have made the appropriate edit in my answer, should you have seen it before my edit. Reload the answer to see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me outline the errors in your code.

You have two form elements bearing the same name, "file"; that's a conflict.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="file">
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` is based on a submit button being named "submit"; it doesn't exist, so nothing in there will be executed.

Therefore, rename your submit button to that, "submit".

Then you have `["Temp"]` which is invalid, all of those should read as `["tmp_name"]` as per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

which is present in

```
$check = filesize($_FILES["file"]["Temp"]);
```

and

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["Temp"], $target_file)) {
```

Then there's this line:

```
$destination = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Uploaded files\CS\Image";
```

there should be two trailing slashes (edit)

```
$destination = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Uploaded files\CS\Image\\";
```

since `$destination . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]` will translate as `folderImage.jpg` where it should be `folder/Image.jpg`, otherwise it will result in an error.

---

- Also make sure that the destination folder has proper permissions to write to.

Comment: `..Image\\"`, or else syntax errors.

Comment: @deceze Thank you, I've made an edit to that effect.

Comment: Also, the condition at the end was correct already! Your "fixed" version will always be `false`.

Comment: @deceze You mean in regards to the `&&`? `if($filetype != "jpg" || $filetype != "png" || $filetype != "jpeg"` etc?

Comment: Yes. *Not X and not Y and not Z* is correct; *not X or not Y or not Z* will always match because something can't be X, Y and Z at the same time.

Comment: @deceze Ok, I understand what you mean. I didn't explain myself properly and is what I meant to write. I've made an edit, thanks again.

Comment: I don't care about the explanation, your *code* is wrong!

Comment: @deceze I'm not catching then. Please feel free to make an edit. OP accepted the answer so I don't know what else I should be doing or not doing.

Comment: OK, fixed it for you.

Answer (score -1):

"Temp" is not a valid key.  Instead, use tmp_name

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["Temp"], $target_file)) {
```

should be

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
```

Comment: and this is 50% right.